# Pyspark error on creating dataframe: 'StructField' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm facing a little issue when creating a dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, types

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()

df_test = spark.createDataFrame(
    ['a string', 1],
    schema = [
        types.StructField('col1', types.StringType(), True),
        types.StructField('col2', types.IntegerType(), True)
    ]
)

## AttributeError: 'StructField' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I don't see anything wrong with my code (it's so simple I feel really dumb). But I can't get this to work. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were most of the way there!

When you call `createDataFrame` [specifying a schema](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema), the schema needs to be a `StructType`. An ordinary list isn't enough.

> 1. Create an RDD of tuples or lists from the original RDD;
> 2. Create the schema **represented by a `StructType` matching the structure of tuples or lists** in the RDD created in the step 1.
> 3. Apply the schema to the RDD via createDataFrame method provided by SparkSession.

Also, the first field in `createDataFrame` is a list of rows, not a list of values for one row. So a single one-dimensional list will cause errors. Wrapping it in a dict that explicitly identifies which columns hold which values is one solution, but there might be others.

The result should look something like:

```
df_test = spark.createDataFrame(
    [{'col1': 'a string', 'col2': 1}],
    schema = types.StructType([
        types.StructField('col1', types.StringType(), True),
        types.StructField('col2', types.IntegerType(), True)
    ])
)
```

Comment: This only works when I have a single value in each column. How to add several rows? i.e. how to replace 'a string' by ['a,'b','c'] and similarly for col2?

Comment: If You need to define more then one value to DF: source_df = S.spark.createDataFrame([
            ("first", "a"), ("second", "b"), ("third", "c")
        ], schema="first_name string, second_name string")