# AttributeError: 'StructType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, azure, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to create spark dataframe from pandas dataframe. I am constructing schema based on that which consists of structype and structfield of array. Below is the sample schema:

```
mySchema = (
    StructType(
        [
            StructField("country_code", StringType(), True),
            StructField("unit_id", StringType(), True),
            StructField("date", DateType(), True),
            StructField("health_category_car_door", StringType(), True),
            StructField("reason_car", StringType(), True),
            StructField("reason_landing", StringType(), True),
            StructField(
                "reasonDetails_car_door",
                StructType(
                    [
                        StructField(
                            "car_doors",
                            ArrayType(
                                StructType(
                                    [
                                        StructField("opmode", StringType(), True),
                                        StructField("count", IntegerType(), True),
                                        StructField(
                                            "window_length", IntegerType(), True
                                        ),
                                    ]
                                ),
                                True,
                            ),
                            True,
                        ),
                        StructField("landing_doors", StringType(), True),
                    ]
                ),
                True,
            ),
        ]
    ),
    StructField("health_category_landing_door", StringType(), True),
    StructField("num_yellow_preds_in_last_14_days", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField(
        "reasonDetails_landing_door",
        ArrayType(
            StructType(
                [
                    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
                    StructField(
                        "causes",
                        ArrayType(
                            StructType(
                                [
                                    StructField("opmode", StringType(), True),
                                    StructField("count", IntegerType(), True),
                                    StructField("window_length", IntegerType(), True),
                                ]
                            ),
                            True,
                        ),
                        True,
                    ),
                    StructField(
                        "num_yellow_preds_in_last_14_days", IntegerType(), True
                    ),
                ]
            ),
            True,
        ),
    ),
)

sparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(df_new, mySchema)
sparkDF.printSchema()
```

It is giving the error.

```
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    938         elif isinstance(schema, (list, tuple)):
    939             # Must re-encode any unicode strings to be consistent with StructField names
--> 940             schema = [x.encode("utf-8") if not isinstance(x, str) else x for x in schema]
    941 
    942         try:
```

While debugging i do understand schema needs to be updated as mentioned in article([Pyspark error on creating dataframe: 'StructField' object has no attribute 'encode'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55814111/pyspark-error-on-creating-dataframe-structfield-object-has-no-attribute-enco)) but unable to understand how i need to update the schema.Can anyone guide ?

Comment: provide full schema and sample pandas data.

Comment: '{"country_code":"xxx","unit_id":"xxx","date":1691280000000,"health_category_car_door":"xxx","num_yellow_preds_in_last_14_days":10,"reasonDetails_car_door":{"landing_doors":null,"car_doors":[{"opmode":"xxx","count":10,"window_length":1}]},"reason_car":"High count","health_category_landing_door":"xxxx","reasonDetails_landing_door":{"car_doors":null,"landing_doors":[{"id":"xx","causes":[{"opmode":"xxx","count":1,"window_length":14},{"opmode":"xxx","count":10,"window_length":1}],"num_yellow_preds_in_last_14_days":1}]},"reason_landing":"High count."}'  - Sample data and schema updated in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you use `df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(<your_data>))` on these data to create pandas dataframe and converting it to spark providing schema.

I have tried this, even I got same error as you.

[image]

The reason you get this error because the schema should be of `StructType` having `StructField`.

In your schema if you observe clearly some `StructField` are out of `StructType`.

You can use below schema for it, I tried to look how the data in pandas dataframe.

[image]

Here, you can see **landing_doors** , **car_doors** are row names and **reasonDetails_car_door**, **reasonDetails_landing_door** is of type list or array.

So, I modified schema as below and tried, it worked successfully.

```
  import pandas as pd
  import json
  from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType,ArrayType,DateType,MapType,LongType
  
  data = '{"country_code":"xxx","unit_id":"xxx","date":1691280000000,"health_category_car_door":"xxx",
  "num_yellow_preds_in_last_14_days":10,
  "reasonDetails_car_door":{"landing_doors":null,"car_doors":[{"opmode":"xxx","count":10,"window_length":1}]},"reason_car":"High count","health_category_landing_door":"xxxx",
  "reasonDetails_landing_door":{"car_doors":null,"landing_doors":[{"id":"xx","causes":[{"opmode":"xxx","count":1,"window_length":14},{"opmode":"xxx","count":10,"window_length":1}],"num_yellow_preds_in_last_14_days":1}]},
  "reason_landing":"High count."}'
  
  sc = StructType([
      StructField('country_code', StringType(), True),
      StructField('unit_id', StringType(), True),
      StructField('date', LongType(), True),
      StructField('health_category_car_door', StringType(), True),
      StructField('num_yellow_preds_in_last_14_days', LongType(), True),
      StructField('reasonDetails_car_door',
          ArrayType(
              StructType([
                  StructField('count', LongType(), True),
                  StructField('opmode', StringType(), True),
                  StructField('window_length', LongType(), True)]),True),True),
      StructField('reason_car', StringType(), True),
      StructField('health_category_landing_door', StringType(), True),
      StructField('reasonDetails_landing_door',
          ArrayType(
              StructType([
                  StructField('causes',
                      ArrayType(
                          StructType([
                              StructField('count', LongType(), True),
                              StructField('opmode', StringType(), True),
                              StructField('window_length', LongType(), True)]),True),True),
                  StructField('id', StringType(), True),
                  StructField('num_yellow_preds_in_last_14_days', LongType(), True)]),True),True),
      StructField('reason_landing', StringType(), True)])
      
json_data = json.loads(data)
sparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(json_data),sc)
sparkDF.printSchema()
```

Output:

[image]

Or
You can create spark dataframe without using pandas,and providing schema as below.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType,ArrayType,DateType,MapType,LongType

mySchema = StructType([
    StructField("country_code", StringType(), True),
    StructField("unit_id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("date", StringType(), True),
    StructField("health_category_car_door", StringType(), True),
    StructField("reason_car", StringType(), True),
    StructField("reason_landing", StringType(), True),
    StructField(
        "reasonDetails_car_door",
            MapType(StringType(),
                ArrayType(StructType([
                    StructField("opmode", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("count", IntegerType(), True),
                    StructField("window_length", IntegerType(), True),]),True,)),True),
    StructField("health_category_landing_door", StringType(), True),
    StructField("num_yellow_preds_in_last_14_days", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("reasonDetails_landing_door",
        MapType(StringType(),
            ArrayType(StructType([
                StructField("id", StringType(), True),
                StructField("causes",ArrayType(StructType([
                    StructField("opmode", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("count", IntegerType(), True),
                    StructField("window_length", IntegerType(), True)]),True),True),
                StructField("num_yellow_preds_in_last_14_days", IntegerType(), True)]),True)),)
    ])
    
json_data = json.loads(data)
sparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(data=[json_data], schema=mySchema)
display(sparkDF)
sparkDF.printSchema()
```

Output:

[image]